# Tableau Server - charts renders not updating (filter across multi published sources)

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

**Issue only seen on Tableau Server not Tableau Desktop**

Using parameters im filtering across **multiple published tableau sources**

The filters work fine, meaning the numbers are filtering through.

However Upon "removing filter", i.e. selecting the "All" options to show all value, Bar charts are not "refreshing", it renders on top of the existing view. See attached screenshot

All other visuals, that are not bar-charts render correctly. Has anyone seen this issue ?

*I also tried filtering using data blending and am facing the same issue*

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I have never seen this before, possibly a browser cache issue? Do you have any updates on this?